# Django: get attributes values

Tags: python, django

I want to get all attributes values, but unfortunately , I got only one which is getting from self.name

My models.py

```
    class Container(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=13)   # Example: MSKU 907032-3
    iso_type = models.ForeignKey(Container_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    weight = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    terminal = models.ForeignKey(Terminal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    arive_time_to_terminal = models.DateTimeField()
    port = models.ForeignKey(Port, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    CY = models.DateTimeField()
    ETD = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    order_added = models.DateTimeField()
    
# Change ALL null=False exception STATUS, time = DateTimeField    
    
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.number
```

Views.py

```
def terminal(request,id):
terminal = Terminal.objects.get(name=id)
container = Container.objects.all() #terminal_id=1



   
return render(request, 'main/terminal.html', {'title': 'Terminal', 'terminal': terminal, 'number':container  })
```

and template is:

```
    {{ weight }}
{{ terminal }}
{{ arive_time_to_terminal }}
{{ Container.port }}
{{ CY }}
{{ ETD }}
```

Many Thanks

PS What I have now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkz4q.jpg)

Comment: you have to run a loop in your template. to get the data from context variable . you pass queryset as context variable

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have got only self.name( Another instances I cannt get.

Comment: you have edit this query for single object in view.
container = Container.objects.filter(terminal__id = id)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but filtering is another question. I attached photo what I have now, and I need filled out table

Comment: {% for item in   number %}
    {{ item.weight }}
{{ item.terminal }}
{{ item.arive_time_to_terminal }}
{{ item.container.port }}
{{ item.CY }}
{{ item.ETD }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Many THANKS, it is working.

Comment: then am giving it as answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for item in number %} {{ item.weight }} {{ item.terminal }} {{ item.arive_time_to_terminal }} {{ item.container.port }} {{ item.CY }} {{ item.ETD }} {% endfor %}
```